Simulation of photon correlation measurements for entangled photons generated in SPDC
I am trying to simulate the measurement that one would have corresponding to type-I spontaneous parametric downconversion (SPDC), for the case when we have say a single-photon -sensitive time-stamping camera. So the signal and idler are generated and then the camera records the time-stamps and the spatial coordinates of the single photons arriving at the sensor camera. I would then want to use this to plot the joint probability distribution (JPD), which can be done if I simulate the measurements. Can anyone guide as to how should I be going about this. I started with the following steps but don't think it gives me a suitable approach:

An intensity map is generated with a certain number of photons, given by the pair generation rate times the time interval we are considering. this corresponds to the intensity we see in the final measurement, which is after sufficient photons have been detected on the sensor.
Time tag each of the pairs.
Select a random pixel co-ordinate, the probability will depend on the intensity map.
Initiate a random number (<1)for this pixel. If the detection probability is greater than this 'random probability', then we register that particular signal photon.
select the diametrically opposite point. If the detection probability here is greater than the 'random probability', then we register that particular idler photon. (so, if both signal and idler are detected, they will have the same time stamps).

However, I am not sure if this is the right way to go about it. Also, I come across papers that say that data was simulated using Monte-Carlo method. How can this be used for the simulation, any suggestions or guidance in this direction ?
These are the two experiments which I am wanting to achieve:
https://arxiv.org/abs/1506.09198
https://opg.optica.org/ol/fulltext.cfm?uri=ol-48-13-3439&id=532148
